# How to tell py to select only wannable things?

Tags: python

I have been trying to make a simple py script that will check if the result is different. It should check for password and one number from 0-100, and there are 3 possible answers:Wrong, Try again
and the last one which I need(and don't know it, so I am trying to pull that out).
This is intended to be like a script for **brute forcing**.

```
p="Wrong!"
a="Try again."
for i in range(00, 100):
        print("SuperPassword " + str(i))  
        if not(p) and not(a):
                break
                print i
                break 
        else: 
                continue
```

It just prints all numbers and doesnt stop till it end(it should stop at right digit password), and how to tell python to print 00 as password since it prints 0 no matther what I type(for e.g. for i in range(00,100) it prints 0,1,...) 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What string are you intending to hold the password to find? `if not(p) and not(a):` is just checking if the two strings at the top are empty, which they aren't and never will be. Is "SuperPassword" the password?

Comment: What does "wannable" mean?

Comment: Wannable is the things you want.

Comment: the output when you run the app with password are represented by **p** and **a**. For. example when you run the app/script you are asked for key word and password. You know key word **SuperPassword** but you are trying to brute the 2 diggets number.

Comment: And the feedback if you type wrong password(2 digit number) is: p="Wrong!" or 
a="Try again.". I was thinking to specify those, avoid them and print just Correct answer.

Comment: So given `password = "SuperPassword99"` and `keyword="SuperPassword"`, you want this to print `SuperPasswordXX` for all `XX` and stop when `XX == 99`?

Comment: no password=2 digits number that you are trying to find with for loop

Comment: I wand to print XX and break when XX is found

Comment: You don't know the password it is in format XX and you want to find it with for loop, when you do you want to break it(btw how to tell py to get like 00 cuz when you type: ```for i in range(00, 100):``` it prints 0 instead of 00 which could be the password.

Comment: Can you please clearly define what your desired output is? The code as shown doesn't make any sense in several key locations (the ``if`` check, exit paths and inner ``print``). Note that this is code for Python2, which is at its end of life since April this year – you should consider upgrading to Python3 as soon as possible.

Comment: Is your question how to format ``0``, ``1``, ``2``, ... as ``00``, ``01``, ``02``, ...? How is your code supposed to check whether the "password" is correct?

Comment: I think I get it. There's _another_ app that wants a password. It prints `Try again.` or `Wrong!` when given an incorrect password. The OP wants a script to brute force the other app's password and print the correct password and whatever the app outputs when the password is correct. @aurora How did I do? Why isn't any of this in the question?

Comment: @hmm you helped thx but still it doesn't stop when it gets to right password

Comment: @MisterMiyagi how can you consider that it is py2 while **This is py3**!!!

Comment: @aurora ``print i`` is invalid syntax in Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a nested for loop...

```
def brute_force():
    for x in range(10):
        for y in range(10):
            p = '%d%d' % (x, y)
            print p
            if p == '87':
                print 'Right!'
                return

            print 'Wrong!'
```

Comment: Yes but how do I specify an stdin(standard output) since app will give me "Wrong" if XX is not writem and ```p=='87' ``` I cant do that since I dont know password. So is there a way to specify that output (that "Wrong") to be avoided, and only true result given.

Comment: Have you understand I have app that says its wrong password if its wrong and so I tried to avoid that wrong output with ```p="Wrong!"
a="Try again." if not(p) and not(a): ``` So the only one password matches and returns correct.

Comment: I have only the faintest idea what you're trying to say. Maybe take a look at `input()` to get the password and just get rid of any `print` lines you don't want. Good luck.

Comment: How can you understand? **You have an IPhone for example,It wants you to type a key-word, and password. You know key word, but dont know pass. So you try to make a brute force script to find out what the number(XX) is. If it is incorrect it prints out "Wrong" or "Try again" so you want the 3rd output. And you try to search if there is any input that results 3rd output(which you dont know it could be correct or right,...)**

Answer (score 0):

given that we have little information on the question. I suggest that you start with this.

```
p = 0
for i in range(0, 100):
    print("SuperPassword " + str(i))
    if p == i:
       break
```

you should be comparing p (i guess that it is password) with i.

Comment: No I can't do that, cuz I don't know the password. Imagine that you specify password and key word with one script(lets call it X), and that you must make a brute force script to get into it. And your line to get into the X is in this form: key word(which you know)  password(which you try to brute, and is 00 like 2 digets)